# Monitoring Yarn/Cloudera application logs in production

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera, production

I am NOT talking about Cloudera or Yarn system level logs. I am talking about applications running on Cloudera/Yarn infrastructure.

We have tens of Java and Python applications running on our Cloudera Infra, and all of them generate application logs. I am looking for the best way to monitor these logs for any errors and warnings. If it is a pure stand alone Java application, traditionally we can use one of these log scraper tools that send emails based on an expression matching (to detect error/warning/any other special situation). I am looking for something similar, that can monitor our application logs and emails us in real time for better production application support.
If thinking about this like a traditional application log monitoring is not the right way, then I am happy to know if there are any better industry standard approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the ElasticStack (https://www.elastic.co/de/) could be one approach to solve this. You could use FileBeats to send your application logs to Logstash which forwards it to ElasticSearch. You could then create a Watcher in Kibana which sends i.e. Emails based on some triggering condition (we use a webhook to send notifications into a MS Teams channel).

This solution should work at least in near-realtime (~1-2 minutes delay, but this also depends on your watcher configuration).

Comment: We have a mix of Python/Java/Shell script-based jobs.. does ES work with all those? I thought it's just for Java Stack?

Comment: ES is independent of the programming language. It is just a storage and analytics engine which is designed for log data. Data can be ingested into ES using Logstash or Beats. 
Which one is appropriate depends on your architecture. From what you wrote I guess you are running multiple different applications which produce logfiles. In this case I think [Filebeats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.10/filebeat-overview.html) would provide a minimal invasive way to send data to ES. You can also run all these components in docker containers.